# Updating the current branch from parent branch

Tags: git

I created a new git branch `B` from branch `A` with tracking option.

Now, when `A` branch gets updated by few commits, I want to pull the commits to `B` as well, so I can keep track of it, and do not have to face big change sometimes later.

How should I approach this? Is it automatically done in git?

Comment: Is tracking branches actually add anything besides saying that branch A feeds from branch A?

Comment: You should rebase your branch B with A.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This is not made automatically. You have to manually merge your changes from A to B, which is pretty simple. Just switch to branch B and do

```
git merge A
```

Which will automatically merge your changes from A to B. As long as you don't have any conflicts, all of the changes in A will be marked as merged in B. A common best practices is to make daily merges, but that is dependent on the number of users/commits using your branch.

Comment: If you are talking about A being a remote branch and B being a local one, git pull is enough

Comment: When I do git merge A from branch B, and there is at least 1 file conflicting, there are files that appear in the changes (staged)! Then after resolving the conflict, I am forced to commit changes that were already commited. What is wrong?

Comment: ```git merge origin A ``` should enhance this further

Comment: what about a `git rebase A` ?

Comment: Don't forget that you have to do a `git push` after merging the parent branch.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I got it to work.

My approach is that I am going to create a new folder, and put the below calls (in that same new folder)..so I know I have only "fresh" code on local (but "fresh" (as possible) from the remote server), ( and 'guarantees' i do not have any accidental local changes).  Aka, a "new folder clean" approach.
It will retrieve the 2 branches of interest (freshly/newly retrieved) to local ... and do the merge (locally).  After merge conflict resolutions (if any), it can be pushed to remote.

short version:

```
git checkout  feature/mychildbranch

git branch

git checkout  feature/myparentbranch

git pull

git branch

git checkout feature/mychildbranch

git branch

git merge feature/myparentbranch
```

longer version (explained)  I'll use /* as comments */

```
/* first, make sure you at least have the child branch */
git checkout feature/mychildbranch


/* ok, just show the branches.  make sure at least feature/mychildbranch exists  note the "*" below says "this is the branch i am on" */
git branch
    * feature/mychildbranch
      feature/myparentbranch


/* now checkout the parent branch...note the "switched" happens automatically with the checkout */    
git checkout feature/myparentbranch
    Switched to branch 'feature/myparentbranch'
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/myparentbranch'.

/* now pull, the pull will occur on the branch you are currently on, which should be feature/myparentbranch at this point */    
git pull
    remote: Enumerating objects: 69, done.
    remote: Counting objects: 100% (55/55), done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
    remote: Total 22 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
    Unpacking objects: 100% (22/22), done.
    From https://mygit.hub.com
       96ae0e9..6eb0a03  feature/myparentbranch -> origin/feature/myparentbranch
        * [new branch]      feature/blah blah blah (specific to my stuff only)
       xb99638..x86db6f  master                  -> origin/master
    Updating x6ae0e9..xeb0a03
    Fast-forward
     .../somefileone.txt | 30 ++++++++++++--------
     .../somefiletwo.txt       |  7 +++--
     .../somefilethree.txt  |  6 ++--
     X files changed, Y insertions(+), Z deletions(-)
     create mode 100644 somenewfileone.txt

/* do a git branch just to show that you're on feature/myparentbranch */    
git branch
  feature/mychildbranch
* feature/myparentbranch

/* ok, now (above) you have the latest-greatest feature/myparent, lets do a checkout on the child to switch to the child */    
git checkout feature/mychildbranch
Switched to branch 'feature/mychildbranch'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/mychildbranch'.

/* another sanity check, show you're on feature/mychildbranch */
git branch
* feature/mychildbranch
  feature/myparentbranch

/* finally, the magic.  do a merge from feature/myparentbranch (which you know is local and up to date because of the voodoo above */    
git merge feature/myparentbranch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .../somefileone.txt | 30 ++++++++++++--------
 .../somefiletwo.txt       |  7 +++--
 .../somefilethree.txt  |  6 ++--
 X files changed, Y insertions(+), Z deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 somenewfileone.txt
```

If there are no conflicts, you should be where you want to be.  (remembering this is "local"... now you can do a commit and push to remote)

If there are conflicts, that's a whole new SOF question/answer IMHO.

But to finish out the "complete cycle" (let's say you get the conflicts resolved)

Now is the time to

BUILD your code.  If it works, continue, if it does not build...fix it.

TEST your code.  Run your unit-tests locally.  If the unit tests are broken...then address the issue(s).  Once they work, continue.

At this point, you have your local code healthy.

Now you need to push your code to remote server.

```
git commit -m "Use a meaningful message here"

git push
```

At this point, if you create a PR (or open an existing one) that is trying to do a

```
feature/mychildbranch -> feature/myparentbranch
```

You should only see what is different between your "feature/mychildbranch" and "feature/myparentbranch"... and without any "conflict files" listed in the PR.  (Obviously, it can be a "moving target" if others are checking code into "feature/myparentbranch".)

Comment: ```git merge origin A``` should this save me from going back to parent branch, making a pull there, and then coming back to child to perform rest of things

Comment: if it wasn't for the typo, `/* not pull` to follow to do the `git pull`... if it wasnt for that, this would be 10/10 answer.

Comment: I didn't see it when i wrote the answer (of course).  but I have changed the "not" to "now".

Comment: git merge feature/myparentbranch  will merge/update local feature/mychildbranch from local 
feature/myparentbranch. What to do now to update the remote feature/mychildbranch?

Comment: I updated the answer with a little extra at the bottom.

Answer (score 10):

at child branch B, we can do

```
git merge origin/A
```

This would keep it in sync with parent's origin.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your call to create `B` was `git clone /path/to/server/A`, you just have to do a `git pull` and you're done. That's how [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) works: first it [fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)es the changes from the upstream (the tracked branch `A` in your case), then it [merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)s these changes into the branch that tracks the tracked branch (`B` in your case).

The [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) and [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch3-5.html) discuss that topic in depth, so they're quite worth reading (if you're not in a hurry, read the rest of them too).

Comment: Hey, just wondering. I am not sure if I actually created branch B by cloning from A. I just created a branch `git branch A` with some random option I think. So, if I just do git pull, git complains that `You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge with...`

Comment: @user482594: `pull` is only needed if you want to fetch data from a remote. If you were on `A` and just did `git checkout -b B`, you can simply `merge` (while being on `B`, type `git merge A`).

Comment: @eckes Thanks. I observed an instance of this i.e. I had a branch A, I created a new branch with ```git checkout -b B```, then while on being branch B, I typed ```git pull origin A```, I got updates in both A & B. I was confused about this and this answer explains that.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to do a `git fetch A` and `git merge A`.

[Blog post describing reason for doing it this way](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/)

Comment: +1 for sharing the link. I knew, there was one but couldn't remember it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

from branch B run the below

```
git pull origin A
```

That's it.

*(Make sure you have latest pull of branch A in your local before executing above cmd.)*

Answer (score 1):

For merging with parents:

It is very important to run both commands:

1. git fetch                    [to pull all meta data associated to branches]
2. git merge parentBranchName

Just FYI: Now in your local history/logs you will see list of commits but this will commit your changes associated to parent branch in your local not on remote.

To see your all changes on remote like github, just execute

1. git push

Answer (score 1):

#### Add upstream Git repository

`git remote add upstream <PARENT_REPOSITORY_URL>`

#### Pull remote upstream branches

```
git fetch upstream
```

#### Checkout to the local branch to update

```
git checkout master
```

#### Merge latest changes from the upstream Git repository

```
git merge upstream/master
```